# Creating a Discount Rule using Nools rule engine

Tags: nools

Am trying to create a new discount rule in my e-commerce website.
I thought nools rule engine was the best to implement. but i dont know how to start and where to start. i  have read the documentation also . am not getting anything. Can any one help me with sample code or how to start.? Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 0):

There are examples with the documentation, you should check it. Maybe try to apply to the google group if you have a specific question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nools